# How can I get the tag from a ID?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

`test= (fs.readFileSync('test.txt', 'utf-8'))` Here I store the ID's and then "test" is a string and I'm trying to get the tag from the stored ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have no issues getting the ID, and the "ID" is an actual user ID, you can do `Client.users.cache.get(id).tag`

Comment: Is there something for ID's of players that aren't in your Discord too?

Comment: Yes. You can do `const user = await client.users.fetch(id)`